# Visual Studio 2022 Creating Lots of Temp files in VFSTemp folder , how to stop it?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Ive been using Visual Studio 2022 as main IDE for my dotnet stack , and im seeing a lots of temporary files which are named in fashion as **"vs_randomnumberhere_uractualprojectfilehere.randomnumberhere.cs"** files into the location of
**"user/appdata/local/temp/TFSTemp"** folder , what are this files , and how to stop the visual studio from generating such junks and filling up the C drive ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1301587/how-to-reduce-the-contents-of-the-tfstemp-folder

Comment: @HansPassant i had already checked out this , there is no answer given by ms community members